# How to change conditions of views filters programmatically?

Tags: views

I have a view with a node type filter. I want to change it in some conditions. How do I change this filter in `hook_views_query_alter()`?

Comment: It may be possible to achieve this without coding.  Could you provide additional information about what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: I want to limit results to a content type when user belongs to a specific role.

Comment: Please see mine and JoeS's exchange regarding what exactly you want, in the comments to his answer. Since we're not in agreement, I ask that you clarify.

Answer (score 2):

You specifically ask for altering the View programmatically, and that certainly is possible. I will however suggest an easier way. With Views 3, you can group your filters. This way, you can achieve the effect you are asking for by adding two separate groups of filters.

Group 1: Node:type == [type]

**OR**

Group 2:  User:role == [role] **AND** Node:type == [other_type]

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to alter the content type by User roles by creating a view definition with two pages (or blocks) setting the filter for the content type and another for the user:role.  I am using views 3 in D7, but the filters should be in your versions as well.  If you are not familiar with Views, check out the video series "Taming the Beast" at nodeone.se.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question. With two different displays, the filters won't interact, which I believe is the desired effect.

Comment: Actually I understood that Hamid N. wanted one content type with one user and another with the other user.  Both filters would be used in each page.  However, I am not sure how the view is to be used specifically.  Also, I have not looked into groups much yet, so I'll be checking that out - Thanks